# How can I get Facebook user information by access token?

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, facebook-graph-api

I use Angular 2 Cordova Oauth plugin [https://github.com/nraboy/ng2-cordova-oauth] to implement FB login in my Cordova app.

Then I succeeded fetching user access token. Here is my code.

```
this.oauth.logInVia(this.facebookProvider).then(success => {
  console.log("RESULT: " + JSON.stringify(success));
  // HERE I WANT TO SEND REQUEST TO GET USER INFORMATION
}, error => {
  console.log("ERROR: ", error);
});
```

But I don't know the way to retrieve user details after getting Facebook access token because I don't use Facebook SDK in this app. If anyone know a solution, please answer me it.

Answer (score 8):

You need to make a GET request to [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2) with the access token received.

```
 this.http.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields= "name,gender,location,picture/*any other fields*/&access_token=${access_token}`, new RequestOptions('Headers':new Headers({'Content-type:application/json'}))).then(result=>{});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm gonna try to make this request.

Comment: Actually I got an error of RequestOptionsArgs when I wrote this code. So I set each param by using URLSearchParams and succeeded creating the request. But your answer was really helping to solve my problem, thank you.

Comment: How can I fetch/get the username. I am using passport-facebook with nodsjs.

My scopes are:
['public_profile','user_gender','user_managed_groups','pages_show_list','email']

And, while calling passport-facebook, profile-fields are:
profileFields: ['id','name','email','gender','birthday','displayName','picture.type(large)']

Any idea, how can I get username?
(Just for ref: if profile is https://www.facebook.com/charels.woodson, then I want "charels.woodson")